2+1-dimensional $SU(N)$ Yang-Mills Theory
In recent years, there has been significant progress and growing interest in conducting quantum simulations of field theories using quantum devices. This typically involves formulating a Hamiltonian representation of the field theory and developing quantum algorithms for simulations on actual devices. Much of this progress focuses on the 1+1D $U(1)$ Schwinger model or the 2+1D $SU(2)$ or $SU(3)$ non-Abelian gauge theories, primarily pure Yang-Mills theories.
I am not familiar with the perturbative calculations discussed in the literature for these lower-dimensional field theories. Are 2+1D $SU(2)$ and, more broadly, $SU(N)$ theories amenable to perturbative calculations? That is, are they renormalizable and asymptotically free?

From the point of view of perturbation theory, QCD in lower dimensions is essentially identical to QCD in $d=3+1$. Namely, the beta function is negative, which means that the theory is UV complete, renormalizable, and weakly coupled in the UV. In other words, perturbation theory is perfectly fine, with a handful of counterterms being enough to reabsorb all divergences. This perturbative expansion is arbitrarily good at short distances, i.e., at high energies. Exactly the same as in (UV free) four-dimensional gauge theories.
A small difference is that, in $d<3+1$, gauge interactions are superrenormalizable rather than just renormalizable. In other words, the beta function is negative already at tree level, which means that there are even fewer divergent structures in perturbation theory. It is even easier to show renormalizability. In $d=3+1$ the gauge coupling is dimensionless, so adding vertices doesn't improve the UV behaviour, and you have infinitely many divergent diagrams; in $d<3+1$, the coupling constant is dimensionful, so there are a finite number of divergent diagrams.
This small difference also has the effect of making infrared divergences slightly more severe, but this is easy to handle by introducing small masses by hand.

It makes sense that lower dimension regulates the UV divergence better, while IR becomes worse. Does IR safety still hold for the usual IR safe observables? Also, does this mean that coupling constant already flows at tree level? i.e. the anomalous dimension receives contribution at the tree-level? Do you know of any reference?

Also, what about SU(2) or other SU(N)? Are they renormalizable for any SU(N), also regardless of matter contents? i.e. number of flavors?

@Quantization 1) I'm not aware of a specific discussion of IR safety in lower dimensions, although it must be true that, for sufficiently well-behaved observables, the theory is IR safe. 2) Yes, the coupling runs at tree level. A good introductory reference for gauge theories in low dimension is Tong's lectures 3) Any gauge group, with any matter content, is renormalizable in $d<4$. You can take any $N$, any $N_f$, any representation, it's all good.

Two-dimensional Yang-Mills is solvable non-perturbatively. Atiyah and Bott used equivariant cohomology to study the theory. The theory is topological and in the small-coupling regime it is classically equal to BF-theory. This implies that the critical points are flat connections on a surface. It follows that the moduli space $M$ is a symplectic character variety. For $SU(N)$ the partition function is simply the symplectic volume of $M$.
$$Z=\frac{1}{N}\int_{M}\frac{\omega^n}{n!}=\frac{1}{N}vol(M)$$
The quantity $Z$ can be interpreted in the perturbative limit as the large $k$ limit of the Verlinde character formula for GWZW conformal blocks. So it is related to RCFT and hence to Chern-Simons theory. Since flat connections are in correspondence with Higgs-bundles over the surface it is also connected to the geometric Langlands correspondence and spectral curves and what not. The two-dimensional story is very rich and an area of activ research, especially since the work of Gaiotto Tachikawa and Alday which implies that the Verma modules of affine W-algebras arising from BRST quantization of RCFTs by means of quantum Drinfeld-Sokolev reduction on punctured surfaces are isomorphic to the $GL(N)\times GL(2)$-equivariant cohomology of the $SU(N)$-instanton moduli space seen as the supersymmetric localization locus of $\mathcal Q$-fixed points, which are BPS states representing cohomology classes in the chiral ring of twisted supersymmetric Yang-Mills.
A nice review is in Stefan Cordes, Gregory Moore, Sanjaye Ramgoolam, Lectures on 2D yang-mills theory, equivariant cohomology and topological field theories, Nuclear Physics B - Proceedings Supplements, Volume 41, Issues 1–3, 1995, Pages 184-244, ISSN 0920-5632, https://doi.org/10.1016/0920-5632(95)00434-B.
For the three-dimensional case I know that it has a mass gap because the action can be reduces to that of a Toda-field theory.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I don't know much about the 3-dimensional case however, I can maybe provide some insight into the 1+1 dimensional version. In 1+1 dimensions the number of gauge constraints is high enough to go far beyond a perturbative analysis. It turns out that the theory is quasi topological and as such the path integral (on arbitrary manifolds) can be solved exactly. This gorgeous story generalizes to a wide range of models with gauge symmetry in 1+1 dimensions. Indeed from your experience from e.g. 3+1D QED you know that quantizing the theory requires imposing two independent constraints on the degrees of freedom of $A_\mu$. The same essentially holds true in 1+1D where this fully restricts all dynamically propagating local excitations of the theory. Instead, the only dynamical objects of your theory are quasi topological non-local objects i.e. Wilson lines and loops. Now if you are working with a compact gauge group this means that essentially all objects you could ever write down in your theory only depend on the Area of your manifold, its topology (This is what we mean by quasi topological) and can be written in terms of objects known from representation theory. (Specifically characters and matrix elements of the group).
I would guess (based on naive d.o.f. counting) that this story does not generalize to 2+1D but still think it is a beautiful enough solution to let you know about it.
(If you are interested in more details there is a review by Moore et al. [arXiv:hep-th/9411210] that goes into a little bit of detail, as well as some of the foundational papers by Witten [Commun.Math.Phys. 141 (1991) 153-209] that may be of interest, though especially the latter is hard to read)

Thanks a lot for this answer. I'm mainly curious to find more information about 2+1, but this is also useful answer!
